# Upload multiple apk from multiple cpu?

Tags: android, google-play

Fail to upload multiple apk , for multiple cpu.
Must each apk to have a different version?
it is necessary to add and

```
versionName '2.29.011.Sonia'
    versionCode 32
```

from every apk ?

My configuration.

```
  compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'xx.yyy.zzzzzz'
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24 //21 ca sa nu mai dea errorare
    versionName '2.29.011.Sonia'
    versionCode 32
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    // ndk {
    //    abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
    //}
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config1
}

productFlavors {
    cpu_86 {
        minSdkVersion 19
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config1
        targetSdkVersion 22
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86"
        }

    }
    armeabi_cpu {
        minSdkVersion 19
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config1
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi"
        }

    }
    armeabi_v7a_cpu {
        minSdkVersion 19
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config1
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }

    }
    arm64_v8a_cpu {
        minSdkVersion 19
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config1
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a"
        }

    }
    x86_64_cpu {
        minSdkVersion 19
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config1
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86_64"
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed from change `minSdkVersion` and add `versionCode`

code:

```
    productFlavors {
    cpu_86 {
        minSdkVersion 17
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config1
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86"
        }
        versionCode 46
        versionName '2.41.011.Sonia'
    }
    armeabi_cpu {
        minSdkVersion 18
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config1
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi"
        }
        versionCode 47
        versionName '2.42.011.Sonia'
    }
    armeabi_v7a_cpu {
        minSdkVersion 19
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config1
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        versionCode 48
        versionName '2.43.011.Sonia'
    }
    x86_64_cpu {
        minSdkVersion 20
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config1
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86_64"
        }
        versionCode 49
        versionName '2.44.011.Sonia'
    }
    arm64_v8a_cpu {
        minSdkVersion 21
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config1
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a"
        }
        versionCode 50
        versionName '2.45.011.Sonia'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  android {

        // To create different apk per abi
        splits {
            abi {
                enable true
                reset()
                include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
                universalApk true
            }
        }
    }

    import com.android.build.OutputFile

    // Map for the version code
    ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'x86': 3]
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

        // assign different version code for each output
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            int abiVersionCode = project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)) ?: 0
            output.versionCodeOverride = (abiVersionCode * 1000) + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
```